# Place icon inside search field as a button in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I am trying to place the "search_icon" magnifying glass inside of the search field and code it as a button.  This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I am going for, but I need to make the icon clickable, and this is if it is written inside of the scss file.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
      <input *ngIf="!(isMobile$ | async) && (isOnline$ | async)"
      #filterTextInput
      id="filter-text-input"
      class="search-box"
      type="text"
      [value]="itemFilterText$ | async"
      autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
      attr.aria-label="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
      (keyup.enter)="searchForValue(searchString.value)" />
      <mat-icon svgIcon="search_icon"></mat-icon>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you can provide with some custom css.

Here is the demo link: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6c8w8l?file=src/app/app.component.css)

You can do that simply by:

```
<div>
    <input type="text"><i (click)="printMsg()" class="material-icons">search</i>
</div>
```

and css:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

div input {
  height: 25px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

div i {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

You just need to provide the negative margin to the icon and padding-right to the text field so that text won't overlap the icon.
Also, You should provide the click handler in the ts of the respective component.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with some custom CSS styles
for the click event, you can simply use the `(click)` event:
HTML

```
<input *ngIf="!(isMobile$ | async) && (isOnline$ | async)"
      #filterTextInput
      id="filter-text-input"
      class="search-box"
      type="text"
      [value]="itemFilterText$ | async"
      autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
      attr.aria-label="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
      (keyup.enter)="searchForValue(searchString.value)" />
      <mat-icon (click)="doSomething()" svgIcon="search_icon" class="search-icon"></mat-icon>
```

CSS

```
.search-icon {
  position: relative;
  right: 32px;
  top:8px;
  width: 24px;
  height:24px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Inside your componenet

```
doSomething() {
    console.log("I am doing something!");
  }
```

[**See this working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96bv8a?file=app%2Finput-prefix-suffix-example.css)

But that's the ugly way of doing it, since you are already using angular material,  it is better to stick to the material design guidelines. In your case you are using forms so it would be better to use something like this to align your inputs/icons

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-icon matPrefix (click)="doSomething()">search</mat-icon>
  <input matInput type="search" 
   *ngIf="!(isMobile$ | async) && (isOnline$ | async)"
   #filterTextInput
   id="filter-text-input"
   class="search-input"
   [value]="itemFilterText$ | async"
   autocomplete="off"
   placeholder="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
   attr.aria-label="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
   (keyup.enter)="searchForValue(searchString.value)"
  >
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: That does not allow me to make it a button however.

Comment: I'll update my answer, you just need to add the (click) event and it will be clickable

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question well, I use it.

```
  <div *ngIf="!(isMobile$ | async) && (isOnline$ | async)" class=" w-100 input-group">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input 
       #filterTextInput
       id="filter-text-input"
       class="search-box form-control input_pass"
       type="text"
       [value]="itemFilterText$ | async"
       autocomplete="off"
       placeholder="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}"
       attr.aria-label="{{'HEADER.SEARCH.PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}"
       (keyup.enter)="searchForValue(searchString.value)" />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="input-group-text" style="background-color: #fff;" mat-button (click)="()=>{}" >
          <mat-icon svgIcon="search_icon"></mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the final effect will be something like this.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeYpc.png)